# How to parallelize jobs for a list of files using snakemake (beginner question)

Tags: input, output, snakemake

I am struggling with a very simple thing. On input of my snakemake pipeline I would like to have a directory, list its content, and process each file from that directory in parallel. Naively I thought something like this should work:

```
rule all:
    input:
        "in/{test}.txt"
    output:
        "out/{test}.txt"
    shell:
        "echo {input} >> {output}"
```

This ends with the error

```
WorkflowError:
Target rules may not contain wildcards. Please specify concrete files or a rule without wildcards.
```

All the resources I could find start with hard-coding the list of jobs in the script, which is something I want to avoid to keep the pipeline generic. The idea is to just point the pipeline to a directory with a list of files and let it do its job. Is this possible? Seems fairly simple and intuitive, but couldn't find an example showing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what command you used for this rule, but the following workflow should suffice your purpose

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand("out/{prefix}.txt", prefix=glob_wildcards("in/{test}.txt").test)

rule test:
    input:
        "in/{test}.txt"
    output:
        "out/{test}.txt"
    shell:
        "echo {input} >> {output}"
```

`glob_wildcards` is a function by snakemake to find out all the files that match the specified pattern (`in/{test}.txt` in this case), then `.text` is to get the list of strings that match `{test}` in filenames (example: "**ab**" in "in/ab.txt").

Then `expand` can fill the string to the placeholder variable that wrapped by curly bracket, then generate a list of input file names.

So rule `all` wants a list of input files correspond to all txt files in `in` folder, then it would let snakemake execute rule `test` for every file

Comment: How can I modify this to make the first rule do what it does here (i.e. in this example copy files from `in` to `out`) and then list the content of `out` and do some joint operation on these files, say concatenate them into a single output file? 

Here I have problems figuring out how to create the second list dynamically. I think the glob will not work since the files in the directory `out` does not exist when snakemake is launched.

Comment: You can create a `joint operation` rule, simply use the input of rule `all` here for the `joint operation` rule, then replace the input of rule `all` with `joint operation` rule output.